# GPIO.wait_for_edge for raspberry pi 5? how to detect edge from high to low

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pi

many years in my project to detect front of the signal, lets say edge from HIGH to LOW I used the command GPIO.wait_for_edge(10, GPIO.FALLING), but in RAspberryPi5 GPIO library is not works

so How I can replace the command PIO.wait_for_edge for RaspberryPi5 ?